# Powershell Split String at first occurrence of a number

Tags: powershell, split

How would I split a string in Powershell to output everything before the first occurrence of a number.
Example:
String: "r1234"
Output: "r" and "1234"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using -split, with a positive lookahead regex and split count option:

```
PS C:\> 'r1234' -split '(?=\d)',2
r
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $yourdata -split '(?<=\D)(?=\d)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the IndexOf method if you want something specific.

```
$String = "r1234"
$String.IndexOf("1")
1
$String.IndexOf("3")
3
$String.Substring(0,$String.IndexOf("1"))
r
$String.Substring($String.IndexOf("1"))
1234
$String.Substring(0,$String.IndexOf("3"))
r12
$String.Substring($String.IndexOf("3"))
34
```